# Tengo un problema con codeigniter estoy terminando mi primera aplicación pero no puedo conectar a la base de datos para guardar

Tags: php, mysqli, codeigniter

es código no me presenta errores pero no puedo conectar a la base de datos

```
    <?php
class Contactos extends CI_Controller {


function __construct(){

    parent::__construct();
    $this -> load -> model('model_contactos'); 
} 


    public function Index(){
        $data['titulo'] = 'Pagina Principal';
        $this -> load -> view('Plantilla/Header', $data);
        $this -> load -> view('Contactos/Index');
        $this -> load -> view('Plantilla/Footer');
    }
    public function Agregar(){

        $data['titulo'] = 'Agregar nuevo contacto';
        $this -> load -> view('Plantilla/Header', $data);
        $this -> load -> view('Contactos/Agregar');
        $this -> load -> view('Plantilla/Footer');



    }

    public function AgregarContacto(){

        $this -> form_validation -> set_rules('nnombre','Nombre','required');
        $this -> form_validation -> set_rules('ndireccion','Direccion','required');
        $this -> form_validation -> set_rules('ntelefono','Telefono','required');


        if($this -> form_validation -> run() == FALSE ){

        $data['titulo'] = 'Agregar nuevo contacto';

        $this -> load -> view('Plantilla/Header', $data);
        $this -> load -> view('Contactos/Agregar');
        $this -> load -> view('Plantilla/Footer');


        }else{

        $data = array (

                'Nombre' -> $this -> input -> post('nnombre'),
                'Direccion' -> $this -> input -> post('ndireccion'),
                'Telefono' -> $this -> input -> post('ntelefono')

            );

            $this -> model_contactos -> insertar($data);

            redirect(base_url() . 'Contactos/');    

        }
    }
}



?>
```

aca el segundo controlador

```
    <?php
class Home extends CI_controller{

 public function Index(){
    $data['titulo'] = 'Agenda Web';
        $this -> load -> view('Plantilla/Header', $data);
        $this -> load -> view('Home/Index');
        $this -> load -> view('Plantilla/Footer');


 }
}

?>
```

aca el modelo

```
    <?php

 class Model_Contactos extends CI_Model{

  function insertar($data){

     $this -> db -> insert('contactos',$data);
  }

  function getAll(){

    $query = $this -> db -> get('contactos');
    return $query -> result();

  }

 }


?>
```

y aca las vistas

```
    <center><h1>pagina de agregar contacto</h1></center>
<hr/>
<div class="container">
    <?php echo form_open(base_url() . 'Contactos/') ?>

    <div class="row">
    <div class="col-mi-12">
        <div class="input-group">

            <span class="input-group-addon" id="basic-addon1">Nombre:</span>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Tu Nombre Aqui" name="nnombre" aria-describedby="basic-addon1">
        </div>      
    </div>  
</div>

<hr/>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-mi-12">
        <div class="input-group">
            <span class="input-group-addon" id="basic-addon1">Direccion:</span>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Tu Direccion Aqui" name="ndireccion"       aria-describedby="basic-addon1">            
        </div>      
    </div>  
</div>

<hr/>


<div class="row">
    <div class="col-mi-12">
         <div class="input-group">
            <span class="input-group-addon" id="basic-addon1">Telefono:</span>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Tu Telefono Aqui" name="ntelefono" 
            aria-describedby="basic-addon1">        
         </div>
    </div>  
</div>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-mi-12">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success pull-right">Guardar</button>       
    </div>  
</div>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-mi-12">
        <?php echo validation_errors(); ?>      
    </div>  
</div>
<?php echo form_close(); ?>
</div>
```

aca el archivo de conexion de la carpeta config y el archivo database.php

```
$active_group = 'default';
$active_record = TRUE;
$db['default']['hostname'] = 'localhost';
$db['default']['username'] = 'root';
$db['default']['password'] = '';
$db['default']['database'] = 'agenda';
$db['default']['dbdriver'] = 'mysqli';
$db['default']['dbprefix'] = '';
$db['default']['pconnect'] = FALSE;
$db['default']['db_debug'] = FALSE;
$db['default']['cache_on'] = FALSE;
$db['default']['cachedir'] = '';
$db['default']['char_set'] = 'utf8';
$db['default']['dbcollat'] = 'utf8_general_ci';
$db['default']['swap_pre'] = '';
$db['default']['autoinit'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['stricton'] = FALSE;
```

Comment: _no puedo conectar_ no da mucha información. Recibes algún error?

Comment: Yo no veo por ninguna parte el código de conexión a la base de datos.

Comment: el problema es qno recibo nada simplemente no guarda nada en la base de datos

Comment: ya actualice mi post porfavor agradeceria saber cual es el error o si falta algo en el codigo

Comment: Necesitas crear tu objeto conexión. Ignoro cómo se hace con Codeigniter. En PHP puro se tiene una clase llamada  por ejemplo `Conexion`. Ella se ocupa de crear la conexión y devolver el objeto. Para usarla: `$db=new Conexion();` No veo que hagas algo parecido en ningún lado, no puedo hablarte con más propiedad de tu caso, porque no conozco Codeigniter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Te falta este constructor en tu modelo:

```
function __construct()
{
    $this->load->database();
}
```

Comment: gracias probe ya pero aun asi el problema q tengo es q no valida nada no se si el problema sea en el codigo ya lo revise muchas veces

Answer (score 0):

Dentro del controlador Contactos en la función AgregarContacto, la declaración del array 'data' está mal, en vez de utilizar -> debería ir => (reemplazar guión medio con signo es igual) por tanto los datos no llegan al modelo. Espero se solucione, saludos.

Debería quedar así:

$data = array (

```
  'Nombre' => $this -> input -> post('nnombre'),
  'Direccion' => $this -> input -> post('ndireccion'),
  'Telefono' => $this -> input -> post('ntelefono')
```

);

Revisa detalles de uso del array acá:
http://php.net/manual/es/language.types.array.php

Answer (score -2):

Prueba agregando el constructor en tu modelo

```
public function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
}
```